# Install linux mint inside on windows 7 64 bit machine using mint4win

Tags: windows-7-x64, linux-mint

I got a error while installing ubuntu 12.04 in my windows7 64bit machine using wubi later i found the issue, that it needs amd64 ubuntu in win7 64bit machines, now i want to install linux mint 15  on my windows 7 machine(64 bit OS) using mint4win tool is there any issues installing linux mint using mint4win, as mentioned above? plz reply...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/linuxmint/mint4win for detailed instructions and procedure.

Comment: Thanks 4 ur Reply Mr.@AM_Hawk, When I tried to install Linux mint 15 using Dvd, it not showing free space (more than 20 gb not partitioned and not used by windows) in computer(lenovo g6/i5 3rd/) also  I tried to run mint4win it not showing GUI, please provide link for same if any.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't a very good question as there could many things wrong.